# local WCF client server connection: message that no service is listening

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-4

After two years I am coming back to implementing a WCF service. I want for starters to configure a super simple, configuration file free service. I have the servercode below. When I use svcutil to create a proxy all is fine. But when I try to implement a client myself using a ChannelFactory I keep being plagued by the message that no service is listening.... Where is the mistake?

*The Client*

```
Module OnlineLicenceClientConsole

    Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to connect...")
        Console.ReadLine()
        Dim factory As New ChannelFactory(Of IOnlineLicenceCommunication)(New BasicHttpBinding)
        Dim address As New EndpointAddress("http://localhost:8015/Onlinelicence")
        Dim client = factory.CreateChannel(address)
        Console.WriteLine("Client running...")
        Do While (True)
            Dim computerID = Console.ReadLine()
            Dim request = New LicenceRequest With {.ComputerID = computerID, .CustomerID = "X", .ServiceID = "Y"}
            Console.WriteLine(client.GetLicence(request).StatusMessage)
        Loop
    End Sub

End Module
```

*The Host*

```
Module OnlineLicenceServerConsole

    Sub Main()

        Dim baseAddress As New Uri("http://localhost:8015/OnlineLicence")
        Dim host = New ServiceHost(GetType(OnLineLicenceCommunicator), baseAddress)

        Dim serviceBehavior As New ServiceMetadataBehavior With {.HttpGetEnabled = True}
        host.Description.Behaviors.Add(serviceBehavior)

        host.AddServiceEndpoint(
            GetType(IOnlineLicenceCommunication),
            New BasicHttpBinding,
            "OnlineLicenceCommunicator")

        Try
            host.Open()
            Console.WriteLine("Service running")
            Console.ReadLine()
        Catch e As CommunicationException
            Console.WriteLine("Fout: {0}", e.Message)
            Console.ReadLine()
            host.Abort()
        Finally
            host.Close()
        End Try

    End Sub

End Module
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The endpoint address which you're passing to the constructor of `ChannelFactory` is incorrect. The service base address is http://localhost:8015/OnlineLicence, and the relative address of the endpoint you added in the host is `OnlineLicenceCommunicator`, so the endpoint address is http://localhost:8015/OnlineLicence/OnlineLicenceCommunicator.

```
Dim factory As New ChannelFactory(Of IOnlineLicenceCommunication)(New BasicHttpBinding) 
Dim address As New EndpointAddress("http://localhost:8015/Onlinelicence/OnlineLicenceCommunicator") 
Dim client = factory.CreateChannel(address)
```

Comment: As ever your humble, grateful servant!